# How to Signup users on aws cognito and on premise database?

Tags: amazon-cognito

I am currently using AWS Cognito User pools and using their hosted signup page I am able to signup users to my user pool but I would at the same time like to signup the users using my applications own signup api which require the password to be input but only the userMigration trigger contains the password and none of the other triggers include the password so is their a way to capture the password on signup to allow me to signup them on my on premise database too

Comment: You would have to have your own signup page that would internally sign up users to Cognito. I don't understand why you would want to do it anyway, but that's the only option you have.

Comment: its a business requirement in the event we would like to move away from cognito in the future but thanks for the answer